# jdbc connection error with MySQL to netbeans. Error message Got an exception! com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql

I encounter error when connecting my java project to database using MySQL.
I am now using Netbeans 6.8
seems that the database can not be accessed due to the driver error. so my connection code is like below

```
Connection con = null;
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mila";
            String db = "";
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, "root", "");
```

and the error message is stated below

```
Got an exception! 
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

and it points to the line where driver lied.
i already use this code in other project but no problem with it. i have also check the database name and such but no problem with that.

really appreciate for the help. thank you

Comment: Your exception handling is pretty poor. You're only printing the message and not the type. You are now clueless as to the real cause.  That "Got an exception!" message is *your own* text and nothing specific to Java. I suggest to replace that poor `System.out.println()` of `e.getMessage()` by an `e.printStackTrace()` line or, better, just throw it. You'll see that you actually got a `ClassNotFoundException` which is at its own so much more self-explaining: the in the exception message mentioned class is missing in the classpath!

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the operation in a try/catch block and log everything about the exception (e.g. e.printStackTrace(), etc.). Worthwhile enabling JDBC tracing just to see what the DriverManager says... like this: DriverManager.setLogStream(System.out); Oh, an try logging in from mysql's command line just to check server operation..